# $(document).ready not called after Ajax call

Tags: jquery

Here is my main page, when page loads, 'page1' is displayed automatically, whenever radio button is toggled 'div' contents are updated through ajax

```
 <html>
   <input type="radio" name="radioOption" id="page1" checked="checked"/>
   <input type="radio" name="radioOption" id="page2"/>
   <div id="page1"><jsp:include page="page1"/></div>
   <div id="page2"></div>
</html>
```

Ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input:radio[name="radioOption"]').on("click", function(e) {
        $.ajax(url:"url", success:function(result){
           $("#page1").empty();
           $("#page2").html(result); 
        };)
    });
});
```

nothing special about page1 and page2, they are just forms with some inputs and submit button

```
<form name="someForm">
   <input type=text name="userName"/>
    <button type="submit" id="save-button"/> 
</form>
```

Have some form validations that are called onClick of submit button like shown below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#someForm').bind('submit', function(e) {
       someValidationFunctions(); 
 });
```

My issue is, these validations are called when the page first loads normally, they are not triggered after the ajax div calls, what am I missing, any inputs appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `on` for dynamically generated elements..

```
 $(document).on('submit','#someForm', function(e) {
   someValidationFunctions(); 
}
```

it is even better if you use static parent element rather than document itself (performancewise)..

which in your case is `#page2`

```
 $('#page2').on('submit','#someForm', function(e) {
   someValidationFunctions(); 
}
```